# Is it possible to retrieve history after deleted from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history

Is there any way to get back or retrieve history in Google Chrome after the history is cleared ?

Comment: Just wondering if you had any success with the recovery of your Google Chrome History?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/4O7WzcM4Osk - Go to this link. It is said that retrieving history back is impossible. But also there are some links given to retrieve back history, you can try it too.